# php var to jquery failing to update after page reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Know a lot about php but novice at jquery or javascript and I'm trying to update a variable after a form submit.

I have a form that submits to a php page.

```
<form name="FindUser" id="userform" class="invoform" method="post" action="" />
    <div id ="userdiv">
        <p>Name (Lastname, firstname):</p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="inputfield" />
        <input type="submit" name="find" id="find" class="find" value="Find" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Which is echoed back via the below method:

```
<div id="infowrapper">
    <div id="usernameinfo" class="info">
       <?php
          if(isset($_POST['find'])){
             include('includes/find.php');
          }
       ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

One of the vars that comes back from the php page is

```
$hidefields="1"
```

The problem is although I can see php update the var correctly, jquery does not update with this new value. I've tested with an alert box which still displays the var as 0 while php is echoing it as a 1. I can only assume it's cached or something.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#userform").hide();
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){

        var hide = <?php echo $hidefields; ?>;

        if(hide == 1){
            $("#userform").hide();
            $("#infowrapper").show();
            $("#passwordreset").show();
            $("#enabledisable").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#userform").show();
            $("#infowrapper").hide();
            $("#passwordreset").hide();
            $("#enabledisable").hide();
        }
        alert(hide);
    });
</script>
```

Is there some simple line I can add to get jq to update with this new var? I'm so close to getting this finished and it's the last obstacle in a steep learning curve. Then I can do some sweet powershell integration ^^.

Thanks.

Comment: Two `$(document).ready()` functions? Can you not combine them?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this a bit :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userform").hide();
});


$(document).ready(function(){

    var hide = <?php echo $hidefields; ?>;

    function firstAction(){
        $("#userform").hide();
        $("#infowrapper,#passwordreset,#enabledisable").show();
       }
     function secondAction(){
        $("#userform").show();
        $("#infowrapper,#passwordreset,#enabledisable").hide();
       }  

       hide == 1 ? firstAction() : secondAction();


    alert(hide);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I know this, I have plans for each of those down the track and would prefer to keep them individually.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what you try to achieve then ?

Comment: Simply when the php var changes to 1, the jq $hide function updates also. It only updates once.